# DOM Dialogbox with callbacks

Tags: jquery, html, dom, callback

I'm creating a custom dialog boxes with Dom (HTML / CSS / JavaScript / jQuery). Those dialog boxes have buttons and these buttons should have some functions containing instructions to be executed when some specific events are raised (onClick...).

To call these dialog boxes, i create a function to draw(`showMessaging(MsgText, Msgtitle, ClickCallback)`). Those functions have some callbacks (`ClickCallback`) to be executed by those buttons, but when i call the function (`showMessaging`) and pass to it some function to be executed by those buttons when some events are raised, the callbacks are executed instead of the function (`showMessaging`).

Here is the code.

```
function showMessagingWarning(sMessage, sTitle, callbackYes) {
    //Reference
    var overlay = $('<div>').addClass('wb_boxOverlay1_');

    if ($('.wb_boxOverlay1_').length > 0) {
        $('.wb_boxOverlay1_').remove();
    }

    $('body').prepend(overlay);

    var msgBox = $('.wx_dialog_boxes'); //boite de message
    var msgIcon = $('.wb_msg_icon_displ'); //icone de la boite de message
    var msgTitle = $('.wb_ms_title_content'); //titre de la boite de dialogue
    var msgContent = $('.wb_msg_message'); //Contenu du message
    var btnNo = $('.wb_msg_box_button_no');
    var btnYes = $('.wb_msg_box_button_yes');
    var btnCancel = $('.wb_msg_box_button_cancel');
    var btnClose = $('.wb_msg_close_lnk');
    //setting up the class
    var tclass = "wb_dlg_warning";

   //Display buttons
    btnNo.css('display', 'none');
    btnCancel.css('display', 'none');
    btnYes.css('display', 'inline-block').children('span').text('OK');

    //ajout des variables
    msgIcon.addClass(tclass);
    msgTitle.text(sTitle);
    msgContent.text(sMessage);

    btnClose.bind('click', '', function () {
        $('.wb_boxOverlay1_').remove();
        $('.wx_dialog_boxes').fadeOut();
    });


    if (callbackYes) {
        btnYes.bind('click', '', callbackYes);
    }

    btnYes.bind('click', '', function () {
        $('.wb_boxOverlay1_').remove();
        $('.wx_dialog_boxes').fadeOut();
    });

    msgBox.show();
}
```